# Lifted Ford F-150 Shaking Horribly at 70+ mph

Tags: ford, truck, f-150, shaking

So I have a 6” lift on my 2010 Ford F-150 platinum. I have 35” Nitto ridge grapplers with some Moto metal rims. I just got my alignment checked out, tires rotated and one tire rebalanced. My truck shakes SO BAD at 70+ mph. I mean the shaking is so bad that my passenger seat rattles and everything in my truck gets shaken up. I even get bruises on my hips from the seatbelt rubbing. Any thoughts or tips before I start spending money on stuff that may not help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like death wobble. I wouldn't know what causes it in a 2010 F-150, but it usually happens with lifted trucks with worn out steering components.

Comment: If you want high speed stabilty then lowering is better, if you want better rock crawling ability then lifting is better. One reason why F1 cars don’t do off-road very well.

Comment: You could also check your tires for cupping. I don't know how old the tires are or what type but I've seen many lifted trucks have off-road tires the require replacement due to cupping.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check each and every bush, steering or suspension joint for play - they will need to be absolutely perfect as any play will be multipled due to the lift.

Also checking all mounting points for steering components etc.